# Take input from user and execute the python script at the same time

Tags: python

i have a python script name as neural_net.py . It classify the mnist dataset.
What i want to do is to run it via command line by taking input from user.
The following snippet is taking input from user

```
file=input()
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(file).convert('L')
imr=np.array(im).T
single_test = imr.reshape(1,400)
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
plt.imshow(imr)
print("value is",nn.predict(single_test))
```

in command prompt i have to run it as following

```
python neural_net.py
```

execute the above line and then give the input

```
pic_0.png
```

and it return me the output.
What i want is to do the both of above things as a single command such as

```
python neural_net.py pic_0.png
```

Comment: use `file = sys.argv[1]` to get it. If you run with more arguments then you have `sys.argv[2]`, etc. If you need more complex soluton like `script.py --input pic_0.png --output image.png` then see module [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

Comment: i think you can use subprocess for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use in code

```
import sys

file = sys.argv[1]
```

to get it.

Now you can run it as

```
python neural_net.py pic_0.png
```

and `file` will be `pic_0.png`

---

If you run with more arguments

```
python neural_net.py pic_0.png pic_1.png pic_2.png
```

then you will have `sys.argv[2]`, `sys.argv[3]`, etc. with values `pic_1.png`, `pic_2.png`

---

If you need more complex soluton like

```
script.py --input pic_0.png --output image.png
```

then see module [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input')
parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', default='output.png')
args = parser.parse_args()

file = args.input
output_file = args.output
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
I think I realized why you are unhappy. You need to provide a path in addition to the file name, you can either do this with args like

> python run.py "c:/users/user/desktop/pictures/pngs/file.png"

and use the original answers. Or simply just put a general path in the code and use the arg for the specific file.

```
IMAGE_FOLDER = "c:/users/user/desktop/pictures/pngs/"
file = IMAGE_FOLDER + sys.argv[1]
```

Original:

This is pretty much straight from google results:

CML:

```
    python neural_net.py pic_0.png
```

Code:

```
     import sys
     print sys.argv[1]
```

Result:

```
    "pic_0.png"
```

Many thanks for Google and 
https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, given this post and @furas, who also answered as I would've expected is also downvoted.

Comment: maybe someone understand question in different way and he downvoted answers. I think your answer is correct for this question.